# How to enable security in HBase?

Tags: hbase

I want to enable authentication and authorization in HBase. I read their documentation which states that it can be enabled using Kerberos but I still could not figure out a proper way to implement it. I'm using HBase Java API. Please suggest how can I use security features of HBase.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the documentation here:
http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#hbase.secure.configuration

you have to add configuration properties in both hbase-site.xml for the server-side (Master & Region Servers) and client side.

from a code point of view, depends what you have to do. 
you can just run your app after a kinit
or you can use the AuthUtil class
https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/master/hbase-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/AuthUtil.java#L49